# Form is submitted but not saving value in database

Tags: python, django

When I submitted this form, instead of saving the value it takes and save it to the database, it submitted the form but the value is none when I check admin page, the form is submitted and redirected me to home page, but the value that a form takes is none when I check my admin:

Model:

```
class Column(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     select_type = models.ForeignKey(Type, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
```

views:

```
class CreateColumn(CreateView):
    model = Column
    template_name = 'column_create.html'
    form_class = ColumnForm
    success_url = 'home'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateColumn, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['formset'] = ColumnFormSet(queryset=Column.objects.none())
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super(CreateColumn, self).form_valid(form)
```

Form:

```
class ColumnForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Column
        fields = ['name', 'select_type']

ColumnFormSet = modelformset_factory(Column, fields=('name' 'select_type'), extra=30)
```

template:

```
<form method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form}}
   {% for form in formset %}
        {{form.as_p}}
   {% endfor %}
<button type='submit'>Save<button/>
<form/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You form is not submitting because of its not valid, the user field is a required field in your model but you ignored that field in the `ColumnForm` so the form won't submit. In the solution I have made the user filed not required

Update your `form_vaild()` method to

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.save()
    return super(CreateColumn, self).form_valid(form)
```

and in your forms.py

```
class ColumnForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Column
        fields = ['user', 'name', 'select_type']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].required = False
```

Comment: Your answer is not working. Will you please edit it and add some details?

Comment: Getting any error?

Comment: There is no any error after adding: `form.save()`, it submitted the form, but the value is not added in the admin sir.

Comment: add ```{{ form.errors}}``` in your template inside ```{% for form in formset %}```

Comment: nothing's changed sir, Even after adding everything you have added in your answer.

Comment: can you confirm that form_valid is getting called? but putting a debugger of print statement? you dont have to call me "sir".

Comment: The `user` is saved in the admin or database, but the `name` and `select_type` is not save in the database, that meant the `form_valid()` is working.

Comment: Great, in the form_valid see if name is select_type is coming or not?

Comment: How can I check that? do you mean: I should use the print statement in the `form_valid()` function? Like: `print('name', 'select_type')`

Comment: Yes print or better pdb, ```import pdb; pdb.set_trace()```

Comment: try form.data['name']

Comment: Using print statement, instead of showing the value in my terminal, it shows `name` and `select_type`, but using `form.data['name', 'select_type']` it throws me an error: `Multi Value Dict Key Error`: `('name', 'select_type`)`

Comment: try form.data['name'], form.data['select_type'] separate.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but it throws another error: `Multi Value Dict Key Error at /column-create 'name'`

Comment: how about form.data ?

Comment: It is the method that throw this error.

Comment: no thats not the method, due to some reason your data in not coming up to form_valid ? can check in the network tab of you browser with preserve logs enabled to check whether data is sending or not?